# one rep max calculator

Tags: javascript, math, dom

rep max calculator and I'm having a bit of an error with my calculation.

the formula for calculation is `(((weight*reps)*0.0333)+weight)`

```js
const submit = document.querySelector('.submit');
let weight = document.querySelector('#weight');
let reps = document.querySelector('#reps');

submit.addEventListener('click', function() {
  result = (((weight.value * reps.value) * 0.0333) + weight.value);
  console.log(result);
})
```

```html
<div class="cardbody">
  <label for="weight"> Lift:</label>
  <input class="input" id="weight" type="text" name="weight" placeholder="weight" required>
  <label for="reps"> Reps:</label>
  <input class="input" id="reps" type="text" name="Reps" placeholder="Repitions" required>
</div>

<div class="cardsubmit">
  <button class="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```

now I tried to manually enter my variables so in the javascript made the `weight=165` and `reps=6`
the output that I'm expecting is `197.96` and what I'm getting is `32.967`, what I noticed is that my program is not adding the weight at the end.`(((weight*reps)*0.0333)+{{weight}})` << I put in double brackets

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that weight.value is a string

You need to convertIt to number to add it correctly
I've used +weight.value but you can use parseInt instead

```js
const submit = document.querySelector('.submit');
let weight= document.querySelector('#weight');
let reps= document.querySelector('#reps');



submit.addEventListener('click', function(){
    result = +weight.value +(((weight.value * reps.value)*0.0333));
    console.log(result);
})
```

```html
<div class="cardbody">
    
        <label for="weight"> Lift:</label>
        <input class="input" id="weight" type="text" name="weight" placeholder="weight" required>
        <label for="reps"> Reps:</label>
           
        <input class="input" id="reps" type="text" name="Reps" placeholder="Repitions" required>
        </div>
        
        <div class="cardsubmit">
        
       <button class="submit">Submit</button>
    

</div>
```